# jquery validator for field which was previously hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

There is a field which is hidden / visible based on radio.

so while loading page we make it visible hidden based on radio value

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if(edit) {
          populateData();
        }

        $(radio).change(function(){
            //here also we show hide text box based on radio value
        })

        function PopulateData() {
            //This does select radio and based on same show / hide text field
        }

       $("myForm").validate(); // attaching validate . At this point field could be hidden or visible


       $(savebutton).click(function(){

         /*This does not validate text 
          field (visibleBasedOnRadio) which was hidden and made visible by either of above */

          if( $("myForm").valid() == false) {
              return false;
          }
       });
    });

<form id="myForm">
<radio>
  <option 1>
  <option 2>
</radio>

<input type="text" id="visibleBasedOnRadio" class="required" style="display:none"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what framework are you using for the presentation logic. I wil try to be as generic as i can.

Lets add two variables to the form.

1. radioButtonValue - which holds the value of the radio button selected. say, for example option1 or option2. You can set a default value to this field so that that particular option is selected by default when the page loads.
2. valueOfTheVisibleField - This field holds the value of the input text box which is visible once the radio button is selected.

   ```
   <form>
     <input type="radio" name="radioButtonValue" value="option1"> Option 1<br> //This is checked.
     <input type="radio" name="radioButtonValue" value="option2"> Option 2<br>
     <input type="text" id="visibleBasedOnRadio" class="required" name="valueOfTheVisibleField" style="display:none"/>
   </form>
   ```

Now in your validation check first the value of the radio button. Only if its value is option2 i.e, when the required field is displayed... only then check if the text box value is present. if not don't do anything related to the valueOfTheVisibleField field because its hidden.